# Symfony - Dump colors into template

Tags: symfony, twig, objdump

I've seen that we can syntax highlight [`dump()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html)ed variables into templates by installing xdebug.

I installed it on Ubuntu with

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

Trying to dump an array

```
{{ dump(my_array) }}
```

I'm now getting the html markup for the highlighted syntax but escaped in the HTML

```
&lt;pre class=&#039;xdebug-var-dump&#039; dir=&#039;ltr&#039;&gt;
&lt;b&gt;array&lt;/b&gt; &lt;i&gt;(size=2)&lt;/i&gt;
  0 &lt;font color=&#039;#888a85&#039;&gt;=&amp;gt;&lt;/font&gt; 
    &lt;b&gt;array&lt;/b&gt; &lt;i&gt;(size=11)&lt;/i&gt;
```

Why is it coming escaped ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Twig escapes markup by default.

In order to see formatted output, use the [raw filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)

```
{{ dump(my_array)|raw }}
```

Comment: I find this weird that `dump()` does not return already escaped result